# asp net error the process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have an error with regards to the subject above, basically I am just downloading a file from its path. My download code is this:

```
string sFile = Request.QueryString["RFBNumber"].ToString();
string sFile2 = Request.QueryString["FolderName"].ToString();
string sFlag = Request.QueryString["Flag"].ToString();

//CreateRFBReport(sFile, sFile2);
//CreateSingleFile(sFile2, sFile);
if (sFlag == "1") {
    sFilename = "RFB_" + sFile + "_COLLATED.PDF";
    sGlobalFolderName = sFile2;
    sFilePath = @ "" + sGlobalFolderName + "\\" + sFilename;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] buff = client.DownloadData(sFilePath);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", buff.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
}
if (sFlag == "2") {
    sFilename = "SOP_" + sFile + "_COLLATED.PDF";
    sGlobalFolderName = sFile2;
    sFilePath = @ "" + sGlobalFolderName + "\\" + sFilename;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] buff = client.DownloadData(sFilePath);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", buff.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
}
```

I have to refresh the page multiple times before I can download the item, however I am having an error on the line `byte[] buff = client.DownloadData(sFilePath);`

Can anyone help me please? Been searching a way to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: can u post what error is?

Comment: the error is this "the process cannot access the file 'c//RFB//PDF//RFB0001.pdf' because it is being used"